# How can I get the equivalent form of this list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have the following list in Python:

```
M = np.array([image_array_to_vector1,image_array_to_vector2,image_array_to_vector3,image_array_to_vector4])
```

where each item represents an image that has been converted to a vector using the `ravel()` function.

`M` in this case looks as follows:

```
[[165 176 186 ...,   0   1   1]
 [ 46  44  46 ...,  57  49  44]
 [ 97 113 109 ...,  46  49  69]
 [139 111 101 ..., 244 236 236]]
```

Rather than doing that manually as shown above, I did the following instead:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        image = Image.open(root + '/' + file)
        image_array = np.array(image)
        image_array_to_vector = image_array.ravel()
        X.append(image_array_to_vector)
```

When I `print X`, I get the following:

```
[array([165, 176, 186, ...,   0,   1,   1], dtype=uint8), array([46, 44, 46, ..., 57, 49, 44], dtype=uint8), array([ 97, 113, 109, ...,  46,  49,  69], dtype=uint8), array([139, 111, 101, ..., 244, 236, 236], dtype=uint8)]
```

Is the second form considered the same as the first one? As the second form includes `array` and `dtype` in the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` is a NumPy array and `X` is a list of NumPy arrays. They are different.
One difference is that `X` would have the methods of a list (such as `append`, `remove`, and `extend`) while `M` has the methods of a NumPy array (such as `reshape`, `size`, and `searchsorted`).

While some NumPy functions may operate on `X` as though it were `M` (because under the hood, the function calls `np.array` or `np.asarray` on its argument), you probably should not count on this. If you want `X` to be a NumPy array, defining it to be one explicitly.

Assuming all the arrays in `X` have the same shape, you can make `X` into one NumPy array (which should be the same as `M`) using `X = np.array(X)`.

```
import os
X  = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file))
        image_array = np.array(image)
        image_array_to_vector = image_array.ravel()
        X.append(image_array_to_vector)
X = np.array(X)
```